# Проблема с подключение к Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Не могу сделать пуш в репозиторий выдает :

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 52.167.219.168 port 22: Broken pipe
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Выполняю команду ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/olga/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/olga/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/olga/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/olga/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/olga/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/olga/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/olga/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/olga/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 
Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: 
<implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: 
<implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 
SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/olga/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA 
SHA256:/wQCjwGyC2laAEdUXcr8kURJLZoXMZICsd/iMFMJI5E /Users/olga/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA 
SHA256:zjTcF8NgV8hXmFqe+klbXEvVcbACOmjUJZcs3VurgI0 /Users/olga/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 535
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to gitlab.com ([52.167.219.168]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 
   0
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: PTY allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: PTY allocation disabled.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com 
reply 1
packet_write_wait: Connection to 52.167.219.168 port 22: Broken pipe
```